# Deleting / Editing ATL COM DLL properties / methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, com, atl

I have created a COM ATL DLL in VS2012.
Adding events and properties is very easy.
However, I see no easy way to edit or delete an event or a property.

VS2012 automatically creates a lot of code for the event or property when I use the Add Wizard, and I am not sure if I should really delete or change this automatically created code manually when I made a mistake and want to replace or delete something.

Is there a way to edit and delete them in a clean way? 
Perhaps there is a property / event manager somewhere in VS2012, but I did not find it.

Thank you!

Comment: You edit their declaration on IDL, and then project stop building until you respectively fix that on your C++ implemetnation - that's it.

Comment: @RomanR. Your reply is the best. Can you make it the answer, please?

Comment: Here you go - see extended answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edit declaration of the methods/properties of your interest on IDL, and then the project stops building until you respectively fix it by reflecting changes on your C++ implementation - that's it.

IDL changes along with implementation updated respectively builds you updated DLL.

Be aware that applications which are already built against earlier method/property set might be in trouble after the update. Related earlier questions you might be interested in (you might, however be not - *which I sense is the case at the moment*, if your question is about updates while you are developing, and not updates on released module):

- [COM: If I change the parent of an Interface do I need to create a new Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487832/com-if-i-change-the-parent-of-an-interface-do-i-need-to-create-a-new-interface)
- [Would adding a new function to the existing COM interface break its binary compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258154/would-adding-a-new-function-to-the-existing-com-interface-break-its-binary-compa)
- [Why is it necessary to add new events to the *end* of an IDL interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856321/why-is-it-necessary-to-add-new-events-to-the-end-of-an-idl-interface)